# How to proxify emails?

Tags: email, proxy, alias

I'm running a store platform for which buyers coordinates are sensitive. In order to prevent sellers to store the buyers coordinates to be independent, I am looking for ways to alias phone numbers and emails.

So far, I've found [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com) which seems great for SMS and Call with Virtual Phone Numbers.

But I can't find a similar way for emails. Is there any I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Mandrill allows just that. They propose a concept of Domains and Routes in Inbound which allows to intercept emails.

Mandrill `POST`s the mail to your endpoint. Then you can do whatever you want.